# How to generate different number but not for same person?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL function that generates a number and I associated that function with a column in a table. But the thing is that I want to generate different numbers for different people, and if I find the same person with multiple entries in the DB, it gives the same number to that person.

For example:

| ID | NAME | NIF | NUMBER_GENERATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 123 | 55555555 |
| 2 | Amy | 456 | 56556565 |
| 3 | Carlos | 789 | 98765443 |
| 4 | Carlos | 789 | 98765443 |

Currently it generates diferent number for everyone, and I dont know how to do the part of "can't generate different number for same person".
My identifier for "same person" is the column NIF, its like the persons social security number.

This is the update I'm doing (NNP is the function):

```
UPDATE RNP_PROF_IDENT_NNP SET NNP = GEN_NNP;
```

Function:

```
create or replace function gen_nnp 
RETURN NUMBER IS
  num_len NUMBER(20) := 0;
  orig_num NUMBER(20) := 0;
  result_num NUMBER(20):=0;
  i NUMBER(10):=1;
  modulo NUMBER(9) :=0;

BEGIN
    orig_num := seq_nnp_gen.nextval();

    num_len := length(orig_num);

    dbms_output.put_line('i' || i); 
    dbms_output.put_line('num_len' || num_len); 

        WHILE (i <= num_len)
        LOOP
            result_num :=
                result_num
                + TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (orig_num, i, 1))
                  * (10 - i);
            i := i + 1; 

            dbms_output.put_line('soma' || result_num); 
        END LOOP;

        modulo := MOD (result_num, 11);
        dbms_output.put_line('resultado modulo ' || modulo); 

        result_num := 11 - modulo;

        IF (result_num >= 10)
        THEN
            result_num := 0;
        END IF;         

    result_num := orig_num ||result_num;

    dbms_output.put_line('result_num' || result_num); 

    RETURN result_num ;
END;
```

Comment: well you already asked this question again.  Edit this and show a [mcve] including the function.

Comment: Well your problem stems from violating the *normal form*. Maybe you should start here and create a table with `PK NIF`  and store the generated number there....

Comment: If you're stuck with that data model and non-deterministic function, are you just doing a one-off update - which use a CTE to generate the distinct values and then apply to multiple rows - or will this also be applied on the fly as new rows are added?

Comment: @AlexPoole as new rows are added, new numbers will be generated and the check to see if that person exists will need to be made

Comment: NNP can't be the function since it's the target of the assignment. If you want to get the same value for a name, you could make a function that accepts an input parameter and generated a value based on that. 
But I think your actual problem is (lack of) normalization. If you'd have a separate `person` table, you can make 1 unique row per person, which contains their `name`, `nif` and `nnp`, and use their `personid` in your `rnp_prof_ident_nnp` table.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally as it was said in the comments, your data should be normalized so you do not need to maintain the same data in multiple rows for the same "person".

You can do this using two separate update statements.

First, assign a `number_generated` to each person. I used `NIF` as the unique identifier, but if there is another way to uniquely identify them, you can use that.

This will assign a number to the lowest `ID` for each person.

```sql
UPDATE RNP_PROF_IDENT_NNP
   SET number_generated = GEN_NNP
 WHERE     number_generated IS NULL
       AND id IN (  SELECT MIN (id)
                      FROM RNP_PROF_IDENT_NNP
                  GROUP BY nif);
```

Once each unique person has a number, you can update the rest of the rows to grab the value that was assigned from the previous update.

```sql
UPDATE RNP_PROF_IDENT_NNP r1
   SET r1.number_generated =
           (SELECT r2.number_generated
              FROM RNP_PROF_IDENT_NNP r2
             WHERE r1.nif = r2.nif AND r2.number_generated IS NOT NULL AND ROWNUM = 1)
 WHERE r1.number_generated IS NULL;
```

Once your existing data has been cleaned up (you can run the updates several times if you wish), you can use this INSERT statement similar to the one below for creating new records.

```sql
INSERT INTO RNP_PROF_IDENT_NNP (id,
                                name,
                                nif,
                                number_generated)
     VALUES (5,
             'James',
             202,
             COALESCE ((SELECT number_generated
                          FROM RNP_PROF_IDENT_NNP
                         WHERE nif = 202 AND number_generated IS NOT NULL AND ROWNUM = 1),
                       GEN_NNP));
```

Comment: This won't work well in multi-session systems. Two sessions, both executing that statement at the same time (that is, second session would start before the first one commits), would both generate a new NNP for James. It's really quite hard to fix this using triggers alone, especially since Oracle doesn't have deferred triggers. For this and various other reasons, normalization is by far the best solution in this case. Your answer seems to imply that your update is normalization, but it's not. For normalization, the duplicate data would be extracted to a separate table.

Comment: As suggested go with normalization process to maintain same Id for same person. Need to have master data for user and use that table to update or if not exists , create record in master and use same value to update.

Comment: Does the generated number be 4 or 8 byte integers? if you accept 16 byte values, MD5 can be used for this purpose (Oracle has: `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT =>
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (Column Name)) [Alias Name]` to generate MD5s). There is a very remote possibility (1 in 2-to-the-power-of-128) that two people would have the same MD5.